# Laravel foreach in Controller

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a problem with foraech loop in my controller.
That's my code:

```
$appointments = Appointment::with('user')
    ->with('service')
    ->whereDate('scheduled_on', '>=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
    ->orderBy('scheduled_on', 'asc');

Debugbar::info('$appointments count()='.$appointments->count());
if($appointments->count()) {
    Debugbar::info('pos 1');
    foreach ($appointments as $appointment) {
        Debugbar::info('pos 2'); //not printed
    }
}

return view('admin.appointments.index', ['appointments' => $appointments->paginate()]);
```

And that's what I can see in my debugbar:

```
$appointments count()=1
pos 1
```

So, the $appointments has one element (first log) but I can't loop on it.
In the View file I use

```
@foreach($appointments as $appointment)
```

to show my result in a grid and it work fine.

Comment: Have you tried adding `->get()` to the end of your query? So... `$appointments = Appointment::with('user')
    ->with('service')
    ->whereDate('scheduled_on', '>=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
    ->orderBy('scheduled_on', 'asc')->get();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually getting the data from the query.

This part creates a query builder object and prepares it with the query:

```
$appointments = Appointment::with('user')
    ->with('service')
    ->whereDate('scheduled_on', '>=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
    ->orderBy('scheduled_on', 'asc');
```

Then you do a `$appointments->count()` which will execute the query :

```
select COUNT(*) from `appointements` where date(`scheduled_on`) >= ? order by `scheduled_on` asc
```

This will give you the correct number of results but not the actual results.

When you go to the view you actually execute `$appointments->paginate()` which **does** execute the query. However when you try to loop over a query builder object. That iteration makes no real sense and is likely that nothing happens.

If you want to iterate through the data in the controller you can do:

```
foreach ($appointments->get() as $appointment) {
    Debugbar::info('pos 2');
}
```